# How to get b, a (numerator/denominator) for chained IIR filters?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

Let's say we have 3 filters applied one after another:

```
b, a = iirfilter(...)  # or bilinear(...) or anything else producing b, a
y = lfilter(b, a, x)
b, a = iirfilter(...) 
y = lfilter(b, a, y)
b, a = iirfilter(...) 
y = lfilter(b, a, y)
```

**How to get coefficients `b2`, `a2` equivalent to the 3 filters, such that we can find the result with only one pass of `lfilter`:**

```
y = lfilter(b2, a2, x)
```

**?**

---

**Edit**: convolving does not seem to work:

```
fs = 44100
b2, a2 = iirfilter(2, 2.0/fs * np.asarray([40, 60]), btype='bandstop')  # 50 hz reject
b3, a3 = iirfilter(2, 2.0/fs * np.asarray([85, 115]), btype='bandstop')  # 100 hz reject
b = np.convolve(b2, b3)
a = np.convolve(a2, a3)
w, h = signal.freqz(b, a, worN=10000)
```

gives:

[image]

I tried with `same`, `full`, `valid` parameter for np.convolve, but none of them solved the problem.

Comment: What does the pole-zero plot of cascade response look like?

Comment: I don't know (never did it in Python), but in my example, `y = lfilter(b2, a2, x)` then `y = lfilter(b3, a3, y)` worked (and the filtering is perfect), so I guess it should be possible to find `a, b` such that we can do it in one pass `y = lfilter(b, a, x)`, regardless of the pole-zeros?

Comment: If you move the null of the second filter further away from null of first filter, such as [850, 1000], the  cascade response is correct and shows two nulls.  I suspect the pole-zero locations of the two filters are interfering with one another.  There is no zplane function in scipy, unfortunately, to show pole-zero placement.

Comment: Hm ok @fstop_22, not sure to totally understand... Could you modify the answer and give a working example in this case? (IIRfilter band reject at 50 hz + IIRfilter band reject at 100 hz) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38675/how-to-plot-magnitude-and-phase-response-of-2-cascaded-filters-in-matlab

You can convolve the numerators and denominators seperately

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.signal as sig

# Individual filters
b1, a1 = sig.iirfilter(...)
b2, a2 = sig.iirfilter(...)

# Cascaded filter
a = sp.convolve(a1, a2)
b = sp.convolve(b1, b2)
y = sig.lfilter(b, a, x)
```

For example given, you sample rate is too high and order of composite filter is not long enough to give that much rejection for nulls that close together.  Decrease you sample rate and then interpolate up 44.1 kHz.

Here is results with sample rate reduced to 4410 Hz.

```
fs = 4410.0
b2, a2 = sig.iirfilter(2, 2.0/fs * sp.asarray([40, 60]), btype='bandstop')  # 50 hz reject
w2, h2 = sig.freqz(b2, a2, worN=4096)

b3, a3 = sig.iirfilter(2, 2.0/fs * sp.asarray([85, 115]), btype='bandstop')  # 100 hz reject
w3, h3 = sig.freqz(b3, a3, worN=4096)

b = sp.convolve(b2, b3)
a = sp.convolve(a2, a3)
w, h = sig.freqz(b, a, worN=4096)

f = w/2.0*fs
```

[image]

Then pass output of IIR filter through a 10x interpolating filter to get back to 44.1 kHz sample rate.

OR, reduce filter order:

```
fs = 44100.0
b2, a2 = sig.iirfilter(1, 2.0/fs * sp.asarray([40, 60]), btype='bandstop')  # 50 hz reject
w2, h2 = sig.freqz(b2, a2, worN=4096)

b3, a3 = sig.iirfilter(1, 2.0/fs * sp.asarray([85, 115]), btype='bandstop')  # 100 hz reject
w3, h3 = sig.freqz(b3, a3, worN=4096)

b = sp.convolve(b2, b3, 'full')
a = sp.convolve(a2, a3, 'full')
w, h = sig.freqz(b, a, worN=4096)
```

Which produces at original sample rate of 44.1 kHz

[image]

Comment: Yes, np.convolve.  Sorry.

Comment: See the edit at the end of my question @fstop_22, it doesn't seem to work with `convolve`.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. It's strange that we cannot chain them with fs = 44100, since when applying the bandstops one after another, the filtering works very well. What does `lfilter(b2, a2, lfilter(b3, a3,x))` mathematically do? Can't we rewrite it as a single lfilter, even in this case where 50hz and 100hz are close?