# How to implement multi-band-pass filter with scipy.signal.butter

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, digital-filter

Based on the band-pass filter [here](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093594/how-to-implement-band-pass-butterworth-filter-with-scipy-signal-butter), I am trying to make a multi-band filter using the code bellow. However, the filtered signal is close to zero which affects the result when the spectrum is plotted. Should the coefficients of the filter of each band be normalized? Can you please someone suggest how I can fix the filter?

```
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfreqz, sosfilt
from scipy.signal import spectrogram
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft
import numpy as np


def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype='band', output='sos')
    return sos


def multiband_filter(data, bands, fs, order=10):
    sos_list = []
    for lowcut, highcut in bands:
        sos = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
        scalar = max(abs(fft(sos, 2000)))
        # sos = sos / scalar
        sos_list += [sos]

    # sos_list = [butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order) for lowcut, highcut in bands]

    # Combine filters into a single filter
    sos = np.vstack(sos_list)

    # Apply the multiband filter to the data
    y = sosfilt(sos, data)

    return y, sos_list


def get_toy_signal():
    t = np.arange(0, 0.3, 1 / fs)

    fq = [-np.inf] + [x / 12 for x in range(-9, 3, 1)]

    mel = [5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 1]
    acc = [5, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 3, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 8, 8, 5, 0, 8, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 1]

    toy_signal = np.array([])

    for kj in range(len(mel)):
        note_signal = np.sum([np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * 2 ** ff * t)
                              for ff in [fq[acc[kj]] - 1, fq[acc[kj]], fq[mel[kj]] + 1]], axis=0)

        zeros = np.zeros(int(0.01 * fs))
        toy_signal = np.concatenate((toy_signal, note_signal, zeros))

    toy_signal += np.random.normal(0, 1, len(toy_signal))

    toy_signal = toy_signal / (np.max(np.abs(toy_signal)) + 0.1)
    t_toy_signal = np.arange(len(toy_signal)) / fs

    return t_toy_signal, toy_signal


if __name__ == "__main__":

    fontsize = 12
    # Sample rate and desired cut_off frequencies (in Hz).
    fs = 3000

    f1, f2 = 100, 200
    f3, f4 = 470, 750
    f5, f6 = 800, 850
    f7, f8 = 1000, 1000.1
    cut_off = [(f1, f2), (f3, f4), (f5, f6), (f7, f8)]
    # cut_off = [(f1, f2), (f3, f4)]
    # cut_off = [(f1, f2)]
    # cut_off = [f1]

    t_toy_signal, toy_signal = get_toy_signal()
    # toy_signal -= np.mean(toy_signal)
    # t_toy_signal = wiener(t_toy_signal)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(8, 12))
    fig.tight_layout()

    ax[0].plot(t_toy_signal, toy_signal)
    ax[0].set_title('Original toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_xlim(left=0, right=max(t_toy_signal))

    sos_list = [butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=10) for lowcut, highcut in cut_off]

    # Combine filters into a single filter
    sos = np.vstack(sos_list)

    # w *= 0.5 * fs / np.pi  # Convert w to Hz.
    #####################################################################
    # First plot the desired ideal response as a green(ish) rectangle.
    #####################################################################

    # Plot the frequency response
    for i in range(len(cut_off)):
        w, h = sosfreqz(sos_list[i], worN=2000)
        ax[1].plot(0.5 * fs * w / np.pi, np.abs(h), label=f'Band {i + 1}: {cut_off[i]} Hz')

    ax[1].set_title('Multiband Filter Frequency Response')
    ax[1].set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('Gain')
    ax[1].legend()
    # ax[1].set_xlim(0, max(*cut_off) + 100)

    #####################################################################
    # Spectrogram of original signal
    #####################################################################

    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(toy_signal, fs,
                            nperseg=930, noverlap=0)
    ax[2].pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Sxx),
                     norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.min(Sxx), vmax=np.max(Sxx)),
                     )

    ax[2].set_title('Spectrogram of original toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[2].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[2].set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=fontsize)

    #####################################################################
    # Compute filtered signal
    #####################################################################

    # Apply the multiband filter to the data
    # toy_signal_filtered = sosfilt(sos, toy_signal)
    toy_signal_filtered = np.sum([sosfilt(sos, toy_signal) for sos in sos_list], axis=0)

    #####################################################################
    # Spectrogram of filtered signal
    #####################################################################

    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(toy_signal_filtered, fs,
                            nperseg=930, noverlap=0)

    ax[3].pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Sxx),
                     norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.min(Sxx),
                                                    vmax=np.max(Sxx))
                     )

    ax[3].set_title('Spectrogram of filtered toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[3].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[3].set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=fontsize)

    ax[4].plot(t_toy_signal, toy_signal_filtered)
    ax[4].set_title('Filtered toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[4].set_xlim(left=0, right=max(t_toy_signal))
    ax[4].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[4].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fontsize)

    N = 1512
    X = fft(toy_signal, n=N)
    Y = fft(toy_signal_filtered, n=N)

    # fig.set_size_inches((10, 4))
    ax[5].plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(X)), 'r-', label='FFT original signal')
    ax[5].plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(Y)), 'g-', label='FFT filtered signal')
    ax[5].set_xlim(xmax=fs / 2)
    ax[5].set_ylim(ymin=-20)
    ax[5].set_ylabel(r'Power Spectrum (dB)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[5].set_xlabel("frequency (Hz)", fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[5].grid()
    ax[5].legend(loc='upper right')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    plt.figure()
    # fig.set_size_inches((10, 4))
    plt.plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(X)), 'r-', label='FFT original signal')
    plt.plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(Y)), 'g-', label='FFT filtered signal')
    plt.xlim(xmax=fs / 2)
    plt.ylim(ymin=-20)
    plt.ylabel(r'Power Spectrum (dB)', fontsize=fontsize)
    plt.xlabel("frequency (Hz)", fontsize=fontsize)
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

The following is after using `@Warren Weckesser` comment:

```
toy_signal_filtered = np.mean([sosfilt(sos, toy_signal) for sos in sos_list], axis=0)
```

[image]

The following is after using `@Warren Weckesser` comment:

```
toy_signal_filtered = np.sum([sosfilt(sos, toy_signal) for sos in sos_list], axis=0)
```

[image]

Here is an example where a narrow band is used:

[image]

Comment: For  mulitband passband, you have to apply the filters in parallel.  The way you have constructed `sos`, you are effectively applying the filters in series (i.e. as a cascade from one filter to the next).  The net gain in that case is the product of the gains of the individual filters, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Can you please provide the code to do it in the right way? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: One way you could do it is to apply the three filters separately, and then take the mean of the three filtered signals.

Comment: I think that is something I can do. What do you mean by saying apply the filters in parallel? Are there more sophisticated ways than taking the mean while using scipy.signal.butter?

Comment: You have the data for each filter stored in `sos_list`, so something like this should work: `toy_signal_filtered = np.mean([sosfilt(sos, toy_signal) for sos in sos_list], axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks. I have applied you solution and the result is shown in the last sub-figure above. As we can see the spectrum of the filtered signal do not match exact in the areas of the filtered frequencies. This means that we lose so me frequency information in these bands. Can we improve that?

Comment: Remove the code in `multiband_filter` that divides `sos` by `scalar`.   That should not be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, that function is not used at all in the example I removed it. So it is not the scalar that is responsible for this discrepancy in the frequency results.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. Change `mean` to `sum`.  This requires that the overlap of the passbands of the individual filters is neglegible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier and recommended method is what Warren wrote in comments. Just calculate sum of separately band-pass filtered signals.

That being said, for someone who wants to create and apply *single* multi-band filter, he can try to achieve this by [combining filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949293/how-to-get-b-a-numerator-denominator-for-chained-iir-filters):

- lowpass (to cut everything above last pass-filter),
- highpass (to cut everything below first pass-filter),
- N-1 band-stop filters, where N being number of pass-bands (to cut parts in-between filters).

It may be difficult though to make it stable (be careful with filter orders) and harder to make it steep.

Found it interesting and tried myself:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft
import numpy as np


def multi_band_filter(bands, subfilter_order=5):
    # high-pass filter
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = bands[0][0] / nyq
    b, a = butter(subfilter_order, normal_cutoff, btype='highpass', analog=False)
    all_b = [b]
    all_a = [a]

    # band-stop filters
    for idx in range(len(bands) - 1):
        normal_cutoff1 = bands[idx][1] / nyq
        normal_cutoff2 = bands[idx+1][0] / nyq
        b, a = butter(subfilter_order, [normal_cutoff1, normal_cutoff2], btype='bandstop', analog=False)
        all_b.append(b)
        all_a.append(a)

    # low-pass filter
    normal_cutoff = bands[-1][1] / nyq
    b, a = butter(subfilter_order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass', analog=False)
    all_b.append(b)
    all_a.append(a)

    # combine filters:
    combined_a = all_a[0]
    for a in all_a[1:]:
        combined_a = np.convolve(a, combined_a)
    combined_b = all_b[0]
    for b in all_b[1:]:
        combined_b = np.convolve(b, combined_b)

    return combined_b, combined_a


bands = [[400, 700], [1000, 1500]]

fs = 8000
time = np.arange(0, 1 - 0.5/fs, 1/fs)
signal_to_filter = np.sum([np.sin(2 * np.pi * (freq + 0.01 * np.random.random()) * time + np.pi*np.random.random()) for freq in range(10, 3800)], axis=0)

b, a = multi_band_filter(bands)
filtered_signal = lfilter(b, a, signal_to_filter)
original_spectrum = fft(signal_to_filter)
filtered_signal_spectrum = fft(filtered_signal)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, fs, len(original_spectrum)), np.abs(original_spectrum), color='b')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, fs, len(filtered_signal_spectrum)), np.abs(filtered_signal_spectrum), color='orange')
plt.xlim([0, 4000])
plt.show()
```

### SOS version

```
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft
import numpy as np


def multi_band_filter(bands, subfilter_order=5):
    # high-pass filter
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = bands[0][0] / nyq
    sos = butter(subfilter_order, normal_cutoff, btype='highpass', analog=False, output='sos')
    all_sos = [sos]

    # band-stop filters
    for idx in range(len(bands) - 1):
        normal_cutoff1 = bands[idx][1] / nyq
        normal_cutoff2 = bands[idx+1][0] / nyq
        sos = butter(subfilter_order, [normal_cutoff1, normal_cutoff2], btype='bandstop', analog=False, output='sos')
        all_sos.append(sos)

    # low-pass filter
    normal_cutoff = bands[-1][1] / nyq
    sos = butter(subfilter_order, normal_cutoff, btype='lowpass', analog=False, output='sos')
    all_sos.append(sos)

    # combine filters:
    combined_sos = np.vstack(all_sos)
    return combined_sos


bands = [[400, 700], [1000, 1500]]

fs = 8000
time = np.arange(0, 1 - 0.5/fs, 1/fs)
signal_to_filter = np.sum([np.sin(2 * np.pi * (freq + 0.01 * np.random.random()) * time + np.pi*np.random.random()) for freq in range(10, 3800)], axis=0)

sos = multi_band_filter(bands)
filtered_signal = sosfilt(sos, signal_to_filter)
original_spectrum = fft(signal_to_filter)
filtered_signal_spectrum = fft(filtered_signal)

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, fs, len(original_spectrum)), np.abs(original_spectrum), color='b')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, fs, len(filtered_signal_spectrum)), np.abs(filtered_signal_spectrum), color='orange')
plt.xlim([0, 4000])
plt.show()

w, h = freqz(b, a)
freq_domain = np.linspace(0, fs/2, len(w))
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
plt.plot(freq_domain, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)), 'b')
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the slope of the filter is not very steep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we do it with the option `output='sos'` enabled in the `butter`? In addition, why do you use a high-, band-, and low- pass filter to make the final band pass filter? Can you please provide some feedback?

Comment: @Thoth Yes, it can be used with sos, see update. I use those filters to achieve multi-band pass characteristics. High-pass to cut everything below start of first filter, low-pass to cut everything above last filter and band-stop filters to cut everything between filters

Answer (score 0):

Your Filtered Signals get "multiplicated" by each other because you calculate them in Series. In my code below i changed your code so it calculates your filtered_signals one by one and then plots them one by one on your graphs. I hope thats what you tried to achieve:

[image]

```
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfreqz, sosfilt
from scipy.signal import spectrogram
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft
import numpy as np
import scipy


def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    print(high)
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], analog=False, btype='band', output='sos')
    return sos


def multiband_filter(data, bands, fs, order=10):
    sos_list = []
    for lowcut, highcut in bands:
        sos = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
        scalar = max(abs(fft(sos, 2000)))
        sos = sos / scalar
        sos_list += [sos]

    # sos_list = [butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order) for lowcut, highcut in bands]

    # Combine filters into a single filter
    sos = np.vstack(sos_list)

    # Apply the multiband filter to the data
    y = sosfilt(sos, data)

    return y, sos_list


def get_toy_signal():
    t = np.arange(0, 0.3, 1 / fs)

    fq = [-np.inf] + [x / 12 for x in range(-9, 3, 1)]

    mel = [5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 5, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 1]
    acc = [5, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 3, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 8, 8, 5, 0, 8, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 1]

    toy_signal = np.array([])

    for kj in range(len(mel)):
        note_signal = np.sum([np.sin(2 * np.pi * 440 * 2 ** ff * t)
                              for ff in [fq[acc[kj]] - 1, fq[acc[kj]], fq[mel[kj]] + 1]], axis=0)

        zeros = np.zeros(int(0.01 * fs))
        toy_signal = np.concatenate((toy_signal, note_signal, zeros))

    toy_signal += np.random.normal(0, 1, len(toy_signal))

    toy_signal = toy_signal / (np.max(np.abs(toy_signal)) + 0.1)
    t_toy_signal = np.arange(len(toy_signal)) / fs

    return t_toy_signal, toy_signal


if __name__ == "__main__":

    fontsize = 12
    # Sample rate and desired cut_off frequencies (in Hz).
    fs = 3000

    f1, f2 = 100, 200
    f3, f4 = 470, 750
    f5, f6 = 800, 850
    cut_off = [(f1, f2), (f3, f4), (f5, f6)]
    #cut_off = [(f1, f2), (f3, f4)]
    #cut_off = [(f1, f2)]
    # cut_off = [f1]

    t_toy_signal, toy_signal = get_toy_signal()
    # toy_signal -= np.mean(toy_signal)
    # t_toy_signal = wiener(t_toy_signal)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(8, 12))
    fig.tight_layout()

    ax[0].plot(t_toy_signal, toy_signal)
    ax[0].set_title('Original toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[0].set_xlim(left=0, right=max(t_toy_signal))
    sos_lists=[]
    for cut in cut_off:
        print(cut)
        sos_list = [butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=10) for lowcut, highcut in [cut]]
        sos_lists.append(np.vstack(sos_list))
    # Combine filters into a single filter
    sos = np.vstack(sos_list)



    # w *= 0.5 * fs / np.pi  # Convert w to Hz.
    #####################################################################
    # First plot the desired ideal response as a green(ish) rectangle.
    #####################################################################

    # Plot the frequency response
    for i in range(len(cut_off)):
        w, h = sosfreqz(sos_lists[i], worN=2000)
        ax[1].plot(0.5 * fs * w / np.pi, np.abs(h), label=f'Band {i + 1}: {cut_off[i]} Hz')

    ax[1].set_title('Multiband Filter Frequency Response')
    ax[1].set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('Gain')
    ax[1].legend()
    # ax[1].set_xlim(0, max(*cut_off) + 100)

    #####################################################################
    # Spectrogram of original signal
    #####################################################################

    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(toy_signal, fs,
                            nperseg=930, noverlap=0)
    ax[2].pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Sxx),
                     norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.min(Sxx), vmax=np.max(Sxx)),
                     )

    ax[2].set_title('Spectrogram of original toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[2].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[2].set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=fontsize)

    #####################################################################
    # Compute filtered signal
    #####################################################################

    # Apply the multiband filter to the data
    toy_signal_filtereds=[]
    for sos in sos_lists:
        toy_signal_filtered = sosfilt(sos, toy_signal, )
        toy_signal_filtereds.append([toy_signal_filtered])


    #####################################################################
    # Spectrogram of filtered signal
    #####################################################################

    f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(toy_signal_filtered, fs,
                            nperseg=930, noverlap=0)

    ax[3].pcolormesh(t, f, np.abs(Sxx),
                     norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.min(Sxx),
                                                    vmax=np.max(Sxx))
                     )

    ax[3].set_title('Spectrogram of filtered toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[3].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[3].set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=fontsize)
    for toy_signal_filtered in toy_signal_filtereds:
        ax[4].plot(t_toy_signal, toy_signal_filtered[0])
    ax[4].set_title('Filtered toy_signal', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[4].set_xlim(left=0, right=max(t_toy_signal))
    ax[4].set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[4].set_ylabel('Magnitude', fontsize=fontsize)

    N = 1512
    X = fft(toy_signal, n=N)
    Ys=[]
    for toy_signal_filtered in toy_signal_filtereds:
        Y = fft(toy_signal_filtered[0], n=N)
        Ys.append(Y)

    # fig.set_size_inches((10, 4))
    ax[5].plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(X)), 'r-', label='FFT original signal')
    for bigY in Ys:
        ax[5].plot(np.arange(N) / N * fs, 20 * np.log10(abs(bigY)), 'g-', label='FFT filtered signal')
    ax[5].set_xlim(xmax=fs / 2)
    ax[5].set_ylim(ymin=-20)
    ax[5].set_ylabel(r'Power Spectrum (dB)', fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[5].set_xlabel("frequency (Hz)", fontsize=fontsize)
    ax[5].grid()
    ax[5].legend(loc=0)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

For the Frequency response in your case you should probably dont use a logscaled plot. `ax[1].semilogy` however makes a plot with log scaling on the y-axis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did the plot as you can see above. However, I think the problem is in the combination of the coefficients in the `sos_list` which results in a filtering signal that has zero elements. This affects the last sub-figure, where the spectrum of the filtered signal is also zero.

Comment: ive added some new changes to my answer. maybe this brings you closer to your solution

Comment: Sorry the expected result is a single signal filtered in multiple bands.

Comment: But the individual lines have the form you like? so all you need now is to combine these individual lines into one continous line?